# Font Awesome Bag Icon doesn't show

Tags: font-awesome

Everything works fine with other icons, using the I class HTML, but when I use fa fa fa-shopping-bag per the Font Awesome website's code for that icon, it doesn't show.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem. "font-awesome" was included as part of a package from which we base our website. Specifically, we use BV Commerce which is developed in asp.net. There is a master file which contains the link to font-awesome. You should just have to update the version number in your link to font-awesome.

Since the version may change, first go to the [font-awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) website and look at the footer. The current version number is displayed there.

Next change the version number in your link. The current link at the time of this post is

```
`<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
```

This fixed my problem.

If you have multiple master files, you will need to search your whole solution for all references to font-awesome.

Hope this helps.

Comment: font-awesome 4.6.3

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue, if you are using a local CDN of font-awesome then somehow your fa class changed to icon so you have to use both fa and icon.

try this `fa fa fa-shopping-bag icon icon icon-shopping-bag`.

**If local CDN**
Edit your location of font-awesome file  as well.

```
@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';
src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');
src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') format('woff2'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') format('woff'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
```

Download the fonts as well.

these all are the solution if you are using the CDN from local.

Comment: As I said in my original post, it works for every other icon using the exact same syntax in the exact same conditions. only this specific icon fails.

Comment: `fa fa-shopping-bag` created at v4.5 of font-awesome, so try to use update version of font-awesome.

Comment: I'm pulling directly from Font Awesome, not using a local version. So how do I "update version"?

Comment: Also, as I said before, EVERY other icon works. Including other v4.5 ones. 

Thanks for the downvote though.

Comment: "I'm pulling directly" Means?? Are you using `CDN` or download the total font awesome.